# Как использовать инструмент VM Tracker в XCode

Tags: xcode

Инструмент VM Tracker выдает несколько значений для используемой памяти - Resident, Dirty Size и Virtual Size.

1. Чем они отличаются?
2. Какой-то из них реально соответствует памяти занимаемому приложением, тому что можно увидеть в списке процессов?
3. звездочкаAllзвездочка означает, что это вся память, занимаемая приложением или здесь тоже все непросто?
4. Какой вообще типичный сценарий использования этого инструмента?

[image: VM Tracker XCode]